# Two functions that satisfy inverse function theorem

Tags: inverse-function

I have this problem:

Let $f,g\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ function that satisfy inverse function theorem in $(2,5)$ such that $f(2,5)=g(2,5)=(2,5)$..

$f-g$ satisfy inversion function theorem in $(2,5)$?

What I can't understand is what does  $f(2,5)=g(2,5)=(2,5)$ mean/ could be helpful in order to help me solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: No, for example if $f=g$ then $0$ does not satisfy the inverse function Theorem in $(2.5)$

Comment: Ok thanks.. so also f+g does not satisfy the theorem because f=-g is 0 right?

Comment: Yea, there is the same situation